# Which is the recommended filesystem for VMware Server / ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, filesystems, partition, vmware-server

We have a couple of servers in office with VMware Server as virtualization solution.

We are planning an upgrade of our infrastructure. Some servers will remain with VMware Server, but we want to migrate some others to VMware ESXi.

In both cases we are making a fresh install, and I wonder if there any suggestion/guidelines regarding the host filesystem and its partitions.

**EDIT:**

We are using local storage instead of SAN/NAS external storage, because we are not sure if it is worth it to use them given our office size/requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it all depends.

Are you using local storage for your VM datastores? Or a SAN/NAS?

However, if you're looking just the best guideline for paritions when installing ESXi; Jason Boche has a great article here: http://www.boche.net/blog/index.php/2008/10/24/esx-partitioning-a-lost-art-form-in-esxi/

Comment: We are using local storage instead of SAN/NAS external storage, because we are not sure if it is worth it to use them given our office size/requirements

Answer (score 1):

What are you using for storage?  If you have a iSCSI connected SAN you use [**VMFS**](http://www.vmware.com/products/vmfs/overview.html) cluster file system on the LUN for all your VMDK disks.

[image: VMFS]

Comment: We are using local storage instead of SAN/NAS external storage, because we are not sure if it is worth it to use them given our office size/requirements